# How to detect an arbitrary expression in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to wrap a function call in a function programmatically, for example, I need to transform this...

```
define('src/libs/require.js', ['src/common/bundle.js'], function (imports) {
    debugger;
    test = imports.test;
    imports.fmtNow();
    self.postMessage({
        method: 'injected',
        message: `${performance.now().fmt()}\tloaded:\tsrc/common/bundle.js`
    });
});
```

into this...

```
function inject() {

    define('src/libs/require.js', ['src/common/bundle.js'], function (imports) {
        debugger;
        test = imports.test;
        imports.fmtNow();
        self.postMessage({
            method: 'injected',
            message: `${performance.now().fmt()}\tloaded:\tsrc/common/bundle.js`
        });
    });

}
```

The define call can be anywhere in the module and the third argument can contain any valid js function definition or expression (that evaluates to a function).

I'm figured out I could use (the HARMONY version) of UglifyJS to do this and I can build an AST and find the expression no problem.  Now I have to figure out how to manipulate the AST to add the wrapper and then spit out the modified code.

Is this the right way to go or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: What. Why are you doing this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @naomik I want to programmatically isolate the expression and wrap it in a function. Not clear?

Comment: Right, but why? This sounds like an awful lot like an XY problem

Comment: @naimik I'm modifying a rollup plugin to allow me to`import` into a blob-based web worker. So, I need to transform some source code during he bundling process. I would have thought that wrapping some arbitrary expression in a function would be a common occurrence in bundlers. If it's not then I'll find another way. Maybe you're just asking a Z question?

Comment: *"I'm modifying a rollup plugin to allow me to import into a blob-based web worker. So, I need to transform some source code in the bundling process"* - this context is important and helps people understand why you'd be attempting such a thing. This is your actual task and there might be a better/idiomatic way to go about it instead of what you originally tried. You should update your question with this context, but sorry I won't be able to help you further